# Filter combined_fields result

Tags: elasticsearch

i'm working on a people search website. I already have my databases indexed and it is currently possible to search for a person by first and last name combination.

```
{
   "query":{
      "combined_fields":{
         "query":"' + criteria + '",
         "fields":[
            "SURNAMES",
            "NAMES"
         ],
         "operator":"and"
      }
   }
}
```

And it works fine. But i also have CITY and PROVINCE fields, so i need to get the full result of the previous query and filter by those two fields if the user wants to. It could be only one field CITY or PROVINCE or both or neither.

For example:

I search for: "Elon Musk" it returns 20 results so i need to get all "Elon Musk" living in CITY = "New York".
Can i do this directly in the above query or do i need to take the result and filter? (this is a bit disgusting for big datasets).

I have tried a combination with

```
{
   "bool":{
      "must":[
         {
            "match_phrase":{
               "CITY":"*' + city + '*"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But it does not work.

Thanks.